# If an item can be bought in a shop is it guaranteed to be available for purchase in the catalog?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I am still two days away from getting the T&T Mart so I have been hoarding everything I have bought or found so far 'just in case'. I have officially run out of space in my inventory though. I just wanted to confirm that if something is bought in a store, found in a tree, or balloon that it can be re-purchased?

For example I found a Makar's Mask in Labelle's one day. I feel like it should be a Nintendo Item but I was able to buy it from the store. Does that mean I am guaranteed to be able to purchase it from the catalog anyway because I found it in a store?

I know that Nintendo items that Tommy and Timmy give me for Fortune Cookies cannot be repurchased, and of course any items not in the list of categories (like flowers) [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121319/what-items-can-be-bought-from-the-catalog) cannot be repurchased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the Nooklings store will never sell any furniture item that you cannot order via a catalog. Similarly all items in the Able Sisters shop can be ordered, even "Nintendo" items from them like the Lil' Bro's Hat.

Also note that items found in balloons are often unique; the "balloon" set cannot be ordered from Nooklings' either, just "normal" furniture items (if balloons even still drop that stuff). When in doubt you can always check the catalog itself, it will say "Not For Sale".

Comment: Balloons only drop balloon furniture now, no more normal stuff, sad to say.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have found one item that cannot be reordered once purchased from the Nooklings...a sprinkler. I bought one yesterday from TIY just to catalog it & sold it. Later while looking through my catalog, I noticed that it said "not for sale"...